# Nice looking dates from facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, datetime, momentjs

I want to display the dates from an fb event in a nice manner.

I am getting the event string from fb and then i make this:

```
var eventDate = eventToDisplay.start_date;

var temp = eventDate.split("T");

eventDate = temp[0].split("-");
eventDate = eventDate[1] + "/" + eventDate[2] + " " + eventDate[0];

var eventTime = temp[1].split("+");

var dateStringStart = "  " + eventDate + "    " + eventTime[0];

var start = moment(dateStringStart).format('LLL');

    var time = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font:{
        fontSize : 16,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
        },
    color : '#eee',
    left : "40dp",
    top : "35dp",
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto',
    text : start
});
   Win.add(time);
```

By running it thru moment.js i get the date to display as:

November 9 2012 8:00 PM

And that is good!

But i want to loose the 2012

So if i try to remove the eventDate[0]

it displays as:

November 9 00-1 8:00 PM

So how do i loose the 00-1?

I only want it to display as:

November 9  8:00 PM

I am building this in Appcelerator Titanium.

Comment: What code are you using to run it through moment.js?

Comment: I am using the script from http://momentjs.com/ and then call it through moment(dateStringStart).format('LLL').

Comment: Oh...It was right there in your code and I just missed it...

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the facebook graph api (you've tagged this with facebook-graph-api, so i presume this is the case) you can specify the date format on the api call.

from [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/]:[1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

> You can optionally override the date format by specifying a
>   "date_format" query parameter. The accepted format strings are
>   identical to those accepted by the php date function. For example,
>   https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed?date_format=U returns the
>   Platform page's feed, with unixtime-formatted dates.

so to get November 9 8:00 PM you would call https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed?date_format=F j g:H A